# I am creating a doubly linked list that will alphabetize a list of names, but I am unsure of what to put in the int main( ) function

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Ultimately, the program will print out a list of names in alphabetical order, along with additional attributes associated with that name. In other words, the output screen will read as follows:

```
Ares: Greek, fire, sword.
Freia: Norse, water, bow and arrow.
Poseidon: Greek, horses, ocean.
Thor: Norse, chariot, hammer.
Zeus: Greek, cloud, lightning.
```

Again, the first names are alphabetized in this list, but attributes are printed alongside them. With regards to my int main( ), I'm not sure how I should begin sorting these names and putting them in order. I have an unsorted list that must be sorted (using functions that add/insert these names into the correct order).

```
    //
    // This is a standard library support code to the chapters of the book
    // "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
    //

    #ifndef STD_LIB_FACILITIES_GUARD
    #define STD_LIB_FACILITIES_GUARD 1

    #include <cmath>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <stdexcept>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Helper function to show an error message
    inline void error(const string& errormessage)
    {
    throw runtime_error(errormessage);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #endif // STD_LIB_FACILITIES_GUARD

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    struct Link {
    string name;
    string mythology;
     string vehicle;
    string weapon;

    Link* prev;
    Link* succ;
    Link(const string& n, const string& a, const string& b, const string&c,Link* p = 0,    
    Link* s = 0)
: name(n), mythology(a), vehicle(b), weapon(c), prev(p), succ(s) { }
    };



    Link* insert(Link* p, Link* n)    // insert n before p; return n
    {
    if (n==0) return p;
    if (p==0) return n;
     n->succ = p;        // p comes after n
    if (p->prev) p->prev->succ = n;
     n->prev = p->prev;    // p's predecessor becomes n's predecessor
     p->prev = n;        // n becomes p's predecessor
     return n;
     }

    void print_all(Link *p)
    {
Link *current;
current = p;
while(current)
{
    cout<<"For this link we have: \n";
    cout<<"Name: "<<current->name<<".\n";
    cout<<"Info1: "<<current->mythology<<".\n";
    cout<<"Info2: "<<current->vehicle<<".\n";
    cout<<"Info3: "<<current->weapon<<".\n";
    current = current->succ;
}

    }
    Link * add_after_find(Link *p, Link *n,const string& s )
     {   Link *current = 0;
current = p;
/* empty list */
if(p == 0)
{   cout<<"List is empty so string not found so not added after it. \n";

    return  0;
}
/*  DO WE NEED ONE LINK ONLY */
else if(p->succ == 0)   /* one link only */
{
    if(p->name == s)
    {

        /* add after link with s */
        /* p in front */
        p->succ = n;
        n->prev = p;
        p->prev = 0;
        n->succ = 0;

        return p;      
    }   /* end of if names =  */
    else {
        cout<<"String not found in link listed so not added. \n";
        return p;

    }

}  /* end of one link */

else /* two or more links */

{   
    current = p;
    while(current->succ)
    {
        if (s == current->name)


        {

            /* then n goes AFTER this link */
            n->prev = current;
            n->succ = current->succ;
            current->succ = n;


            return p;
        }  /* end of name matches */

        else 
        {
            current = current->succ;
        }
    }// end of while
    /* if outside of while then we are at last link with a current -> name 
     so s not found  */
    cout<<"String is not found so not add after it. \n";
    return p;
}  // end of else 2 or more
}  // end of function
```

---

```
int main()
{      
    Link*newlist = new Link("Thor","Norse","chariot","hammer");
    newlist = add_after_find(newlist,new Link("Hera","Greek", "horse", "arrow"),"Thor");
    newlist = add_after_find(newlist,new Link("Poseidon","Greek", "ocean", "trident"),"Freia");
     newlist = add_after_find(newlist,new Link("Ares","Greek", "fire", "sword"),"Poseidon");
     newlist = add_after_find(newlist,new Link("Zeus","Greek", "cloud", "lightning"),"Ares");

    print_all(newlist);
    cout<<"Now let's alphabetize these five gods.\n";
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: tl;dr are you having an actual problem, or are looking for someone to solve this for you?

Comment: Ohh. Forgot to specify. I'm mainly looking for someone to help guide me through this with some pseudocode.

Comment: @user994559: You should work on the formatting of the code, in particular indentation and formatting around `if` constructs. Formatting of the code is a great help to reading the code and to avoid subtle bugs, for example, you have one-line `if`s followed by an indented line that is not part of the `if` branch, which makes it hard to read at once.

Comment: Also, you have other problems in your code: Your program leaks memory (what happens to `Poseidon`?), this is a design problem, as your interface does not allow you to handle this particular case. You might want to implement `find` and `add` and then offer `add_after_find` on top of them handling error conditions a little more gracefully. Your list invariants (prev/succ pointers refer to the previous/next elements in the list) are not maintained in all cases (in the case of a list with more than one element, what happens when you find the place for insertion if there are more elements?)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this is homework, if it is not, the simple answer is that you should use `std::list` and the `sort` method in that container.

What to put in `main`? Most probably something on the lines of: `sort_list( newlist )`, where the pointer is passed by reference (as the head of the list will probably change). As of how to implement that, it depends on what sorting algorithm you want to implement, the simplest is probably going to be bubble sort, the next best choice for a list would be merge sort. Google for them, and if you need help with the algorithms, come back and ask.

In the meantime, you might want to work on the issues I raised as comments to the question: code formatting, memory leaks (both while inserting if the position is not found, and at the end of the program), correctness of the data structure at all times... I have not done an in depth analysis, but I have the feeling that your `add_after_find` might fail when it needs to add an element at the tail of the list... Before you start even considering sorting, you should make sure that the input will be correct. It easier to debug the current issues as it is than if you start adding more code.

Comment: It is absolutely easier to debug as you go rather than at the end.  Determining that you have the correct data prior to sorting will save you a lot of headaches in the long run.